# Access sqlite database and images in sub directories of user selected folder - Android

Tags: android, android-intent

I have a folder '**MainFolder**' with the following structure and contents.

[image]

This folder can be any where in my android internal storage or sd card. In my application the user should be able to select the '**MainFolder**' using a directory chooser after which the app needs to access the files in its sub directories.

How can I connect to the '**data.db**' (sqlite database file) and read the image files in the '**profilepic**' folder to be displayed in an image view?

I am using Android Studio 3.2.1

min SDK version :19

Comment: "This folder can be any where in my android internal storage or sd card" -- this will not work on Android Q (by default) or Android R+ (for all apps). For the database, you will need to limit the user to locations for which you have filesystem access, such as `getExternalFilesDir()`.

Comment: So is there any work around?... like copying the data.db to some other location after user selecting the MainFolder?

Comment: You could use `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT` to let the user pick the database, then copy it (using `ContentResolver` and `DocumentFile`) to a file that you control. From there, you can use `SQLiteDatabase` or `SQLiteOpenHelper`. Or, you could use `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE` to have the user pick `MainFolder`. You would then use `DocumentFile` to get to the particular database `Uri`, then copy it to a file that you control using `ContentResolver`.